# Coloumn names in Laravel whereBetween

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

In Laravel

```
->whereBetween('usage.created_at', array('subscriptions.created_date', 'subscriptions.end_date'))
```

It gives query as

```
`usage`.`created_at` between 'subscriptions.created_date' and 'subscriptions.end_date'
```

But I am expecting the query to treat the `subscriptions.created_date` and `subscriptions.end_date` as column itself instead of string value

```
`usage`.`created_at` between subscriptions.created_date and subscriptions.end_date
```

*Removed the quotes from `subscriptions.created_date` and `subscriptions.end_date`.*

From their docs I got this but not suitable for my situation as I want column names instead of `1` and `100`

```
$users = DB::table('users')
->whereBetween('votes', array(1, 100))->get();
```

How can I achieve this. I am New to Laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can do this with two `whereRaw()`:

```
->whereRaw('usage.created_at >= subscriptions.created_date')
->whereRaw('usage.created_at <= subscriptions.end_date');
```

But if you really want to use `whereBetween`, I don't know :/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to use `DB::raw`

```
->whereBetween('usage.created_at', array(DB::raw('subscriptions.created_date'), DB::raw('subscriptions.end_date')))
```